# How to make uTorrent identify the old files so that i can seed them?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I'm downloading a torrent that has 42 files. I initially downloaded 10 files and later due to some problems, i reinstalled my OS. I installed uTorrent and started downloading the same torrent from 11th file. Now, i moved those 10 files back to default folder where files are downloaded but utorrent doesn't seed them and it again download those 10 files.

I want to seed those 10 files. uTorrent doesn't even identify them. How to make it identify old files?

Comment: Try something like Rigth click + "Check Files". Not sure of the exact method though, it's been a very long time since I used µTorrent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself.

I stopped the utorrent and closed it completely, even from tray. I copied those 10 files to original folder. By right clicking on that selected torrent, there's an option called "Force Re-check". Click on it. Now, uTorrent identifies those old 10 files.